# Changing under cabinet spotlight bulbs

Tags: lighting, kitchens, led, halogen

I have pyramid spotlights under my cabinets. Three bulbs have gone and I’m not sure how/if they can be replaced. The bulb housing rotates to change the angle of light, so not a simple turn and pop. Thanks [image]

Comment: A picture of the other side of the fixture as well as of any markings/writing on the fixture (or copy that info into your question as text to make it more readable) would definitely help. All we know right now is that this is some sort of low voltage light, but we don't even know if it's AC or DC controlled. Of course, you could just start experimenting by undoing screws to see what happens... (turn off the power, first!).

Comment: Sure looks like the two screws in the small bar are holding the bulb mount assembly in from the back.

Comment: BTW, if they're old incandescent lamps, replace with equivalent LED's, which should last *much* longer, as well as saving electricity.

Comment: Halogen bulbs are incandescent bulbs, just filled with inert gas and a halogen like iodine.